# How to disable Jackson from deserializing an Instant from epoch millis?

Tags: java, spring-boot, datetime, design-patterns, jackson

I am developing an API using Spring Boot and am using Jackson for payload (de)serialization. I want to deserialize an ISO-8601 formatted datetime into a `java.time.Instant`, but do not want to support deserializing from epoch time in milliseconds or nanoseconds. I want to only support the data being provided to my API in one format to reduce the chance of client error.

Currently, Jackson deserializes to an Instant from both an ISO-8601 formatted string AND from a string containing only numbers e.g. `"20190520"`.

Are there Jackson annotations I can use on my `Instant` field, or properties I can set to apply this kind of behaviour? Or is a custom deserializer my only option?

Comment: I don't think there are settings to enable this. Write your own custom JsonSerializer should be the only way, i.e. `@JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class) private Instant time;`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Are there Jackson annotations I can use on my Instant field, or properties I can set to apply this kind of behaviour? Or is a custom deserializer my only option?

I am not personally aware of annotations that will do this out-of-the-box for you; but the following is a simple deserializer that does the job:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.Instant;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer;

public class JacksonInstantDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Instant> {
    public JacksonInstantDeserializer() { this(null); }
    public JacksonInstantDeserializer(Class<?> clazz) { super(clazz); }
    
    @Override
    public Instant deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext ctx) throws IOException {
        return Instant.parse(parser.getText());
    }
}
```

It basically uses [`Instant.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-); which accepts **ONLY** an [ISO-8601 formatted string](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT) (it will throw a [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html) if the string is not formatted accordingly) and creates an `Instant` based on its representation. Then you can use tell jackson to use this converter to deserialize the `Instant` properties of your DTOs in the following manner:

```
    public class MyDTO {
        @JsonDeserialize(using = JacksonInstantDeserializer.class)
        public Instant instant;
    }
```

[Complete code on GitHub](https://github.com/marco-ruiz/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so-common/src/main/java/so/a56159078)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I figured I'd have to make a custom deserializer. Too bad the Jackson doesn't support disabling integer timestamp parsing.

Comment: To give more help, I had to wrap the deserializer in a module registered with the object mapper. I put a static method on the deserializer to assist: `public static SimpleModule instantDeserializingModule() {
        var module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addDeserializer(Instant.class, new JacksonInstantDeserializer());
        return module;
    }`  and then `new ObjectMapper().registerModule(instantDeserializingModule())`

Comment: @Marco Thank you so much for your answer, really helped me out, for my case the json file was not string, it was the unix timestamp value so I had to use this instead of the parse `return Instant.ofEpochSecond(parser.getValueAsLong());`

Comment: @AyaAki You're welcome, glad to help. Too bad stackoverflow sucks so much with its scoring system, otherwise I'd be answering more questions in detail like with this one. Stackoveflow just took a huge chunk of my points for some weird reason. Done with them! I may start my own blog and take all my work there.